# Batch file won`t start program when launched from windows service

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have created a batch file to run when a specific service stops. 
The batch file should stop the relevant software running, restart some services (stop / start) and start the software again.

It`s a simple code:

```
@echo off
Taskkill /F /IM program1.exe
Taskkill /F /IM program2.exe
timeout /t 5
net stop service1
net stop service2 && net start service2
net start service3
timeout /t 2
start C:/path/program1.exe
start C:/path/program2.exe
```

Have set the service up to run the batch file as recovery at first failure.
Batch file is linked via a shortcut to be able to run it as administrator.

This works perfectly when running the batch file directly, but when it`s executed by the service recovery, the start-up of the software fails.
Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What does "Batch file is linked via a shortcut to be able to run it as administrator" mean?

Comment: In order to be able to execute the batch file, it needs to be run as administrator (right click and "Run as administrator"). Since this file is being executed by another program, it will not be run as administrator. A quick solution (posted at another question) is to create a shortcut, which you then give administrator rights.

Comment: My guess is this method isn't working to run your batch with elevated permissions as a scheduled task. Can check the `Run with highest privileges` checkbox on the scheduled task?

Comment: Is this a typo or just an example of what you are doing?  **start C:/path/progam.exe**  Should it be **start C:\path\program.exe**

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances `timeout /t 5` might cause trouble. Try to replace it with `PING -n 6 127.0.0.1 > NUL`.